# 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute '_aggregate_item_by_item'

Tags: python, pandas

Got error while extracting the latest of date

```
import pandas as pd
data =[[1,'2020-10-25',100,1] , [1,'2020-10-26',200,2], [2,'2020-10-27',300,3],[2,'2020-10-28',400,4],[3,'2020-10-29',500,5],[3,'2020-10-30',600,6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id','date','price','Quantity'])
df.loc[df.groupby('id').date.idxmax()]
```

got error

```
  652                         return self._aggregate_item_by_item(name, *args, **kwargs)
    653                     except (AttributeError):
--> 654                         raise ValueError
    655 
    656         return wrapper

ValueError:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert values to datetimes:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.loc[df.groupby('id').date.idxmax()]
print (df)
   id       date  price  Quantity
1   1 2020-10-26    200         2
3   2 2020-10-28    400         4
5   3 2020-10-30    600         6
```